# Relation of eigenspace of A to eigenspace of $A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ with $\lambda\in\sigma(A).$ I have shown that $\lambda^k\in\sigma(A^k)$ using an induction argument. That is;

We know $Ax=\lambda x$ is true. Assume $A^kx=\lambda^k x$ is true, then by multiplying both sides by $A$ and some manipulation we obtain $A^{k+1}x=\lambda^{k+1}x.$ Hence by induction we obtain the result.

I now need to show that the eigenspace of A corresponding to $\lambda,$ $E_A(\lambda),$ satisfies the relation $E_A(\lambda)\subseteq E_{A^k}(\lambda^k)$ and I am not quite sure how to.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\;x\in E_A(\lambda)\;$ , then $\;Ax=\lambda x\;$ , and from this, by what you've proved by induction:

$$A^kx=\lambda^kx\implies x\in E_{A^k}(\lambda^k)$$